# Automatically Determine Credit Card Type

Tags: jquery, mobile, credit-card

I'm trying to automatically determine credit card type. The code below works, but not on mobile. I've tried finding a solution for mobile, but I'm unable to do so at this time.

Here's the jQuery:

```
(function($) {
   $.getCreditCardType = function(val) {
     if(!val || !val.length) return undefined;
     switch(val.charAt(0)) {
       case '4': return 'visa';
       case '5': return 'mastercard';
       case '3': return 'amex';
       case '6': return 'discover';
     };
     return undefined;
   };
   $.fn.creditCardType = function(options) {
     var settings = {
         target: '#credit-card-type',
     };
     if(options) {
         $.extend(settings, options);
     };
     var keyupHandler = function() {
       $("#credit-card-type li").removeClass("active");
       $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('');
       switch($.getCreditCardType($(this).val())) {
         case 'visa':
          $('#credit-card-type .VI').addClass('active');
          $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('VI');
           break;
         case 'mastercard':
          $('#credit-card-type .MC').addClass('active');
          $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('MC');
           break;
         case 'amex':
           $('#credit-card-type .AE').addClass('active');
           $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('AE');
           break;
         case 'discover':
           $('#credit-card-type .DI').addClass('active');
          $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('DI');
           break;
       };
     };
     return this.each(function() {
       $(this).bind('keyup',keyupHandler).trigger('keyup');
     });
   };
})(jQuery);
```

**ANSWER:**  I added

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

I will give credit to Scott for the help he provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using keypress instead of keyup?

```
$(this).keypress(function() {

});
```

or using the input event of the input field you are monitoring?

```
$(this).on('input', function() {

});
```

**EDIT - Answering your question**

I wasn't really sure what was going on in your code out of context. I changed a few things in the scoping just so I could get things working.

First off, I am going to assume the HTML looks something like this.

```
<ul id="credit-card-type">
    <li>
        <form>
        <input type="text" id="credit-card-type" />
        <input type="text" id="authorizenet_cc_type" />
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then the JS using the input event

```
     var getCreditCardType = function(val) {
        if(!val || !val.length) return undefined;
        switch(val.charAt(0)) {
            case '4': return 'visa';
            case '5': return 'mastercard';
            case '3': return 'amex';
            case '6': return 'discover';
        }
        return undefined;
    }



     var keyupHandler = function() {
         console.log('test')
       $("#credit-card-type li").removeClass("active");
       $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('');
       switch(getCreditCardType($(this).val())) {
         case 'visa':
          $('#credit-card-type .VI').addClass('active');
          $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('VI');
           break;
         case 'mastercard':
          $('#credit-card-type .MC').addClass('active');
          $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('MC');
           break;
         case 'amex':
           $('#credit-card-type .AE').addClass('active');
           $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('AE');
           break;
         case 'discover':
           $('#credit-card-type .DI').addClass('active');
          $("input[id=authorizenet_cc_type]").val('DI');
           break;
       };
     };



    $('input#credit-card-type').on('input',keyupHandler);
```

Comment: How would that work with my code?  I'm not great with jquery.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using an external API.

It would be trivial to integrate, you can transfer the server load to a third party and you can get up to date credit card BIN and IIN information.

There are several around that offer free and paid plans:
https://iinapi.com/
https://www.neutrinoapi.com/